# I have 2 OS on 2 separate SSDs. How does my 3rd SSD get installed/setup?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, installation, pop-os

Basically, I have a dual boot Windows 10 and Pop! OS on two separate SSDs. I installed them independent of each other (remove the other when installing OS).

I want to install my third (or more, later) SSD as storage supplement that can store media mostly. I don’t know if I’ll install large apps, but very unlikely at this point (though I’d like to know if that would change my setup). This SSD should also be accessible from both OSs. I *may* want to encrypt it later, I mention this in case it changes the response.

How should I install this and set it up? Do I need to remove the Windows 10 SSD first and then install it or can I just stick the SSD in, choose ext4 and it’s good to go on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the disk physically and format it, using the most
suitable OS for the disk format that you choose.

Sharing disks between Windows and Linux is not without risk - question of formats:

- ext4 is excellent on Linux and not really supported on Windows
- NTFS is excellent on Windows but only supported on Linux in a limited way
  as regarding user permissions
- FAT32 is well-supported on both, but is a very limited ancient format.

So take your pick.